# In what order should I watch the films in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, suggested-order

What films make up the Marvel Cinematic Universe, and what order should they be watched in?

Comment: Watch them in the order they were released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full chronological (not release order! I assume you're asking for chronological, as release order is easy enough to find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films)) order, bolded the ones that interest (and/or should) you:

> 1. **Captain America: The First Avenger (Film)**
>
>    Agent Carter (One-Shot on the Iron Man 3 Blu-Ray)
>
>    Agent Carter (TV series)
> 2. **Iron Man (Film)**
>
>    > A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to Thor's Hammer (One-Shot on the
>    >     Captain America: The First Avenger Blu-Ray)
> 3. **Thor (Film)**
> 4. **The Incredible Hulk (2008 Film)**
> 5. **Iron Man 2 (Film)** (Hulk's campus rampage can be seen in the background)
>
>    The Consultant (One-Shot on Thor Blu-Ray)
> 6. **The Avengers (Film)**
>
>    Item 47 (One-Shot on The Avengers Blu-Ray)
> 7. **Iron Man 3 (Film)**
>
>    Agents of SHIELD (TV Series: Season 1, Episodes 1-7)
>
>    All Hail The King (One-Shot on the Thor 2: The Dark World Blu-Ray
>      and digital release)
> 8. **Thor 2: The Dark World (Film)**
>
>    Agents of SHIELD (TV Series: Season 1, Episodes 8-16)
> 9. **Captain America: The Winter Soldier (Film)**
>
>    Agents of SHIELD (TV Series: Season 1, Episodes 17-22)
> 10. **Guardians of the Galaxy (Film)**
>
>     Daredevil (Netflix Series)
>
>     Agents of SHIELD (TV Series: Season 2, Episodes 1-19)
> 11. **Avengers: Age of Ultron (Film)**
> 12. **Ant-Man (Film)**
>
>     Agents of SHIELD (TV Series: Season 2, Episodes 20-22)

List taken from [this source](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/48613/20150424/how-to-watch-the-full-marvel-cinematic-universe-in-order.htm). The list was compiled based on clues and/or direct references made between movies and/or info released by creators. I've changed it a little, as the original list was a little inaccurate.

Note that some films are likely happening simultaneously - like Iron Man and The Incredible Hulk.

> Tony Stark's organisation sold anti-Hulk weapons to the army (that had to happen before Tony returned from captivity), and yet at the end he approaches the General with the Avengers initiative as a solution to Hulk (after finishing his first bossfight as IronMan).

Comment: Hmmmm... what's the justification behind watching Ant-Man before the rest of SHIELD season 2?

Comment: @scott.korin that part I don't know. Copies from the source website. I haven't watched either yet, so I didn't read into it to avoid spoilers

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't discuss piracy on Stack Exchange – at least, the use of *download* implied this, sorry if I'm wrong.

Anyway, related to the Avengers, you appear to be missing *Thor*, *Thor 2: The Dark World* and *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*. As you'd expect, you should watch them in release order:

- *Iron Man* (May 2008)
- *The Incredible Hulk* (June 2008)
- *Iron Man 2* (May 2010)
- *Thor* (May 2011)
- *Captain America: The First Avenger* (July 2011)
- *Marvel's The Avengers* (May 2012)
- *Iron Man 3* (May 2013)
- *Thor: The Dark World* (November 2013)
- *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* (April 2014)
- *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (July 2015)

The Marvel Cinematic Universe will probably have a lot of development towards non-Avengers by *Infinity War*. Only *Guardians of the Galaxy* and *Ant-Man* fit that category so far, but I recommend you watch them after *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* to fully understand a few tidbits of plot (which I won't spoil).