# Is there a less fragmented order for watching the Marvel Cinematic Universe before Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, suggested-order, avengers-endgame

As winter turns to spring, a young nerd's thoughts may turn from the brightly-blossoming trees and unfamiliar sunshine, towards the warm and familiar embrace of a [Marvel Cinematic Universe re-watch](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/is-there-an-official-marvel-cinematic-universe-viewing-order) in anticipation of the plucky low-budget upcoming feature presentation *Avengers: Endgame*.

The original release order probably makes most sense, but thanks to the [vagaries of release scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(film)#Theatrical), it can lead to some of the background story threads being a bit disjointed.

For example, the mid-credits scene of *Thor: The Dark World* directly foreshadows *Guardians of the Galaxy*, but when watching in release order we go straight to the mostly-unrelated *Winter Soldier*. Similarly, T’Challa is introduced in *Civil War*, but then we have four other movies before we see him again, right before *Infinity War* (in which he doesn't have a particularly big role).

Is there an order for watching the Marvel Cinematic Universe movies that keeps related plot threads closer together?

Comment: I fail to see how this isn't a dupe of the linked question which whilst asks for the official order the answers give several different orders. Also "better" is entirely subjective so if not a dupe this is borderline (and only borderline because it's suggested-order) POB.

Comment: This must either be a dupe or is primarily opinion based, as "better order" is entirely subjective...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: could be. That question specifically asks for an official viewing order, which discourages the kind of answers my question is looking for. There's only [one answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45654/440) that offers an alternative order for the whole MCU, and that's in-universe chronological. Mine's definitely a bit opinion-based, and of course I'm more than happy for the community to decide whether it's a good question or not.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I don't think "better order" is *entirely* subjective. You can explain what's better about one order as compared to another. Personal preferences will vary, but with 21 released movies and counting, I think it's a potentially useful subject.

Comment: Suggested order questions are always going to be "opinion based" but as a community we decided they are acceptable. The only close argument I see here is as a duplicate, so it is just a matter if you agree with the OP or not since this isn't asking for an "official" order.

Comment: Also I do wonder if this question is facing down-vote from its perceived "opinion" nature, possible duplicate nature, or because it was immediate self-answer..... maybe a combination of all of the above.

Comment: @Skooba It's also worth noting that the OP here deleted their answer on the linked question, asked this and then pasted their answer over.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Indeed. Also, there is already a [marked duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97440/in-what-order-should-i-watch-the-films-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe) which does not ask for "offical order" so at the very least this question would be a duplicate of that, but that one is already closed as duplicate of the "official one".  So I am firmly now in the 'this is a duplicate" camp.

Comment: @Skooba: although my question carefully asked whether there's a better order than the official order, thus craftily preventing itself from being a duplicate! But if we want to make the official MCU order question our one question on MCU order, that's cool. It's also cool if this is too opinion-based.

Comment: But I ask you: if *we* don't step up and produce the canonical answer to this question, *who will?* Look at this incoherent mess that Screenrant belched up: https://screenrant.com/marvel-movies-rewatch-order/ The internet deserves better!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some slight changes from the original release order put crossover scenes/events closer to their eventual pay-off, without confusing the in-universe chronology [any more than it already is](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/which-year-does-spider-man-homecoming-take-place-in).

Movies pulled forward from their original release order are marked in bold:

1. Iron Man
2. **Iron Man 2**
3. The Incredible Hulk
4. Thor
5. Captain America: The First Avenger
6. The Avengers
7. **Thor: The Dark World**
8. **Guardians of the Galaxy**
9. Iron Man 3
10. Captain America: The Winter Soldier
11. Avengers: Age of Ultron
12. Ant-Man
13. Captain America: Civil War
14. **Spider-Man: Homecoming**
15. **Black Panther**
16. **Black Widow** (but move the post-credit scene after *Endgame*)
17. Doctor Strange
18. Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2
19. Thor: Ragnarok
20. Avengers: Infinity War
21. **Captain Marvel**
22. Ant-Man and the Wasp
23. Avengers: Endgame
24. Spider-Man: Far From Home

Defend!

#### Iron Man 2

As [noted elsewhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4653/440), one of the last scenes in *Iron Man 2* includes news footage from the university incident in *The Incredible Hulk*, suggesting that the climax of *Hulk* happens after *Iron Man 2*. Tony's pre-credit appearance in *Hulk* works just as well if we assume he's visiting General Ross in his capacity as a consultant on the Avengers Initiative.

In addition, *Iron Man 2 opens* with Tony's press conference at the end of *Iron Man* playing live on TV in Ivan Vanko's apartment, then skips forward six months, so it flows quite nicely after *Iron Man*.

#### Thor 2 and Guardians 1

*Thor: The Dark World* begins (Dark Elves flashback excepted) with Loki being brought back to Asgard as a prisoner, allowing us to see the immediate fallout of *The Avengers*.

Its mid-credits scene features the Collector, so it's nice to follow it with *Guardians of the Galaxy* to get immediate pay-off there, and to keep the space-based movies together.

Nothing in *Thor 2* or *Guardians* spoils anything in *Iron Man 3* or *Winter Soldier*, which are both set on earth, and have some thematic parallels.

#### Spider-Man, Black Panther, and Black Widow

*Spider-Man: Homecoming* and *Black Panther* can slot in immediately after *Civil War*, so that we get to know the new characters — *Spider-Man*, in particular, follows on directly from that character's involvement in the airport fight, and *Black Panther’s* post-credit sequence pays off *Civil War’s* mid-credits sequence. *Black Widow* also follows closely after the events of *Civil War*.

As long as we skip the *Black Widow* post-credits scene and slot it in after *Endgame*, nothing in these movies particularly affects the post-Civil-War in-universe chronology (even though *Black Widow* came out five… years… later), and this order also:

- puts the *Doctor Strange* mid-credits sequence closer to its payoff in *Thor: Ragnarok*, and the movie as a whole closer to the appearances by some of its characters in *Infinity War* and *Endgame*;
- leaves the tonally-similar space-based *Guardians 2* and *Ragnarok* right next to each other; and
- means the *Ragnarok* mid-credits sequence is followed immediately (well, after a short Goldblum comedy interlude) by its payoff in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

#### Captain Marvel

After the post-credits scene of *Infinity War*, we can meet Carol straight away, then spend time with *Ant-Man* right before his fairly large role in *Endgame*.

Comment: Personally, I'd move Captain Marvel even earlier, somewhere between the 2 GotG movies.  Mainly because GotG2 kind of majorly spoils the twist in Captain Marvel re: the Kree vs. Skrull.  Also it makes her appearance in Endgame a little less Deus ex Machina to establish her earlier in the series.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: I did think about that (Captain Marvel: The Second Avenger!), but the mid-credits scene comes right between Infinity War and Endgame, so it can’t really go anywhere else. Aside from that, you’re spot on, it can pretty much go in anywhere. I think you’re thinking of Guardians 1 somewhat tipping the Kree/Skrull thing, rather than Vol. 2.

Comment: Yeah, I don't count the end credit scenes as part of the movie really.  If you could somehow move the movie earlier but keep the end credits where they are, it would solve that issue.  Kree/Skrull comes up in Guardians 1, but it's much more of a major plot point in 2.  But I wouldn't put Captain Marvel before Guardians 1 because that one was really the best one to introduce the space-themes into the series.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: they're certainly non-essential, although they are a signature feature of the MCU. I think you're wrong about Guardians 2 though — [the Skrulls aren't mentioned at all](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-2017.pdf), and the Kree get a few fairly off-hand mentions that basically refer to their grudge against the Guardians from the first movie, where Ronan is the antagonist (which is what spoils the Captain Marvel reveal of the Kree being maybe not so great).

Comment: In terms of flow, I think it easiest to argue for Captain Marvel's after the first Captain America, to explain where the Tesseract was between 1945 and *Avengers*, and to set up Project Pegasus.